# Adding two objects -- trouble understanding accepting an object as an argument

Tags: java, class, object, parameters, return

I'm working on a project for my Java class. I'm a bit new to this, so I'd appreciate any help. Essentially, I'm building a class that deals with ounces and pounds. An object of the class has two integer variables, one for ounces and one for pounds. One of the methods required for this class requires an object of the class (PoundsOunces) to be taken in as the parameter, added to the calling object, and the sum returned. I've tried different ways to do this but I keep receiving errors. This is the closest idea I've had so far.

```
public PoundsOunces add(PoundsOunces object2) {
    return (pounds += object2.pounds, ounces += object2.ounces);
}
```

Apologies if this is an obvious fix.

EDIT: in our instructions, it was required that a PoundsOunces object be returned.

Here is a UML diagram.
The UML diagram for the class:

### PoundsOunces

- pounds : int
- ounces : int
  (these were the variables, below are the methods)
- PoundsOunces() :
- PoundsOunces(p : int, o : int) :
- simplify() : void
- setPounds(p : int) void
- setOunces(o : int) : void
- getPounds() : int
- getOunces() : int
- toString() : String
- add(object2 : PoundOunces) : PoundsOunces
- equals(object2 : PoundsOunces) : boolean

Comment: Since your specification is to **return the sum** I would assume you must return an `int` instead of `PoundsOunces`

Comment: You need   PoundsOunces class to return.

Comment: Do you want to manipulate the fields in the current object and then return that, or do you want to create a new object with the new sums and return that?

Comment: @dunni I believe the best way would be to create a new object. The only issue I'm coming across with that is figuring out how to get the calling object to be part of that.

Comment: Shouldn't ounces roll over to zero and increase the pound value when you reach 16?

Comment: Can you post the whole class definition of PoundsOunces? Does it have more than the two fields?

Comment: @MickMnemonic yes, I already have a method for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments, you want the calling object to be part of the sum. Then I guess you want to add two object, current object and one passed as reference. Below two method should work. Here, using `this` keyword, we are getting the reference of calling object

```
public PoundsOunces add(PoundsOunces object2) {
    PoundsOunces pounces = new PoundsOunces();
    pounces.pounds =this.pounds + object2.pounds; 
    pounces.ounces = this.ounces+ object2.ounces;
    return pounces;
}
```

and if you want to return the current object, then below should work.

```
public PoundsOunces add(PoundsOunces object2) {
    this.pounds += object2.pounds;
    this.ounces += object2.ounces;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was obvious. I always forget about using this. Thank you so much. Marked as correct.